# Converting dozens of non-member functions to methods?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say we have some `class Foo` and we have many non-member functions that mutate vectors of `class Foo`; i.e:

```
void remove_duplicate_foos(std::vector<Foo>* foos_io) {
  std::vector<Foo>& foos = &foos_io;
  // removing duplicates
}
```

Let's say we have dozens of functions like this that manipulate `Foo` vectors. So we roll up a class called `FooStore` that contains a vetor of `Foo` and has methods to manipulate that `Foo` vector.

```
class FooStore {
  public:
  void remove_duplicates() {
    ::remove_duplicates(&foos);
  }
  private:
  std::vector<Foo> foos;
}
```

Now, is there any handy way to do pretty much this dozens of times? Is it a bad idea to this? Should the function remain non-member only?

Comment: I consider the "class that stores an object just so I can type less" an anti-pattern.

Comment: Having a non member Funktion has the advantage of it being guaranteed to be only using its public interface. Unless its friended. Its called encapsulation. If its vectors of Foo you could have it templated and externalize the too specific behavior

Comment: Having an API like the upper one is quite alright. You can also make a class for vector<Foo> and add all the modifiers as members. I advice against the above pattern, though. It's more code that does nothing (a wrapper), but save a few bytes elsewhere. Plus you then have two interfaces to tend. If you want a more c++-esque interface you might want to replace the upper code by the lower one (and thus copy the function contents into the member instead of calling the other function).

Comment: @molbdnilo Why? It allows you to take better advantage of autocompletion, typing less lowers probability of some minor typing errors, and in some cases clutters the code less allowing better readability. If you deal with several vectors in one place, it gives you better focus on which vector you mutate (as opposed to what to do with the vector in case of non-member function) allowing you to avoid accidentally mutating wrong vector (the trade-off is that you can accidentally call wrong member function). In my opinion it depends on context and which problem you prefer to avoid.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that doesn't deserve to be called "anti-pattern". Rather: think twice before you use it and make sure it's really worth the trouble.

Comment: Before you do this, I recommend to read "How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation" (http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) and "Monoliths Unstrung" (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm). I think there is also an item in Effective C++, so you consult this one too. This may give some background why non-member functions are actually good. Of course, having unified function call as in D would be great improvement to the language. On the other hand, it may be that you spotted a missing abstraction over vector<Foo> in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the benefit of doing this, as you don't want to expose foos to the outside... Also, you don't want to specify the "text" twice by copying/pasting, potentially making a mistake in the forward call.

This more or less solves it using macros:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo{};

void x1(std::vector<Foo>*){}
void x2(std::vector<Foo>*){}
void x3(std::vector<Foo>*){}

class FooStore
{
  public:
#define FOO_STORE_FWD(name)\
    void name()\
    {\
      ::name(&foos);\
    }

    FOO_STORE_FWD(x1)
    FOO_STORE_FWD(x2)
    FOO_STORE_FWD(x3)

#undef FOO_STORE_FWD

  private:
  std::vector<Foo> foos;
};


void testFooStore()
{
  FooStore f;
  f.x1();
  f.x2();
  f.x3();
}
```

Furthermore, I can see the benefit of making a function a friend, but then that function has to "know" about you. In this case it knows about your member, not of you...

---

In c++ 11, it can be modified as follows:

```
#define FOO_STORE_FWD(name)\
    auto name() -> decltype(::name(&foos)){ return ::name(&foos); }
```

this should handle forwarding to functions multiple return types

Comment: You can improve it (in C++11 +) with something like `auto name() { return ::name(&foos); }`

Comment: @Jarod42. I've managed by using decltype. See my mod... Any comments or alterations welcome. I'm surprised it worked. Perhaps someone can elaborate sighting the standard.